# Which class is executed first in Python?

Tags: python

Is it proper practice to have all code within classes? I have one class that does all my calculating and whatnot. But I have all the rest of the code (mainly used to call the class) outside of a class. It looks like this.

```
class bigClass:
  executing here
  functions and whatnot
  blah blah

b=bigClass()
b.bigClassfunction()
```

My question is whether those last two lines should go in a class of their own? Or do I just leave them to float about not bound to a class.

Comment: I think it probably depends on the context, if the functions are only relevant to the class they should be in the class (it can be a @staticmethod or @classmethod).

Answer (score 1):

That's absolutely OK, there's no need to put them in a class. A function could be an option if you need to repeat the code several times.

A class shouldn't be used for things like this; The role of class, as in Wikipedia, is

> In object-oriented programming, a class is a construct that is used to
>   create instances of itself – referred to as class instances, class
>   objects, instance objects or simply objects. A class defines
>   constituent members which enable its instances to have state and
>   behavior. Data field members (member variables or instance
>   variables) enable a class instance to maintain state. Other kinds of
>   members, especially methods, enable the behavior of class instances.
>   Classes define the type of their instances.

Although you can embed this code in a class, it would be unnecessary to put this inside a class if it needs to be executed only once.

EDIT:
As I now understand, the confusion is about how to indicate python which code to run first, like you would do in `java` using a `main` method in the `ProjectName` class. In python, the code runs top-down. Each statement is being calculated on the go. That's why you cannot reference to a class above its definition, for example.

```
obj = Klass()
class Klass: pass #Doesn't work!
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not especially clear but you would **always** put all code related to a class within the class. It makes no design sense to do other wise.

Comment: It's not related to a class. It's just normal code that comes outside of any class. I was just wondering if that code needs its own class and that class was special in such a way that it would execute before all other classes (sort of like a main class in Java). Not necessary, just wondering if it was practice.

Comment: `main` in java is a method, not a class!

Comment: python is not java. no need for classes when they do not support your design.

Answer (score 0):

Some people put their "main" code into a block such as:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
    bar()
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) thread for more information.

Do *not* use classes for the sake of having classes, however. It isn't very "Pythonic".